# How can I post data to UDT through C# Oracle.managedDataAccess dll, UDT created in ORACLE Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-manageddataaccess

Following is MY SP in which I have created A UDT.... SP takes UDT, UDT contains header then it loops through all rows below the header..

I need a way in C# to send data in this UDT in which I am receiving data like below.

```
PROCEDURE PG_ADC_API_SBP_FILE_BATCH  (
    P_PG_SBP_FILE_TAB  PG_SBP_FILE_TAB, 
    P_FLAG OUT NUMBER) 
IS
  
  v_sbp_file_conf_detail_id  pg_sbp_file_conf_detail.sbp_file_conf_detail_id%type;
  v_sbp_file_conf_id  pg_sbp_file_conf.sbp_file_conf_id%type;
  
begin

  v_sbp_file_conf_detail_id := sbp_file_conf_detail_id_seq.nextval;
  v_sbp_file_conf_id := sbp_file_conf_id_seq.nextval;
  
  for i in (select * from table(p_pg_sbp_file_tab)) loop
   
    insert into pg_sbp_file_conf 
       (sbp_file_conf_id, file_path,total_records, total_amount, is_process, process_date,error_message,isactive,entry_date)
    values 
       (v_sbp_file_conf_id,i.file_path,i.total_records, i.total_amount,null,null,null,1,sysdate);    
    insert into pg_sbp_file_conf_detail
       (sbp_file_conf_detail_id,sbp_file_conf_id, file_sr_no,payment_id,channel_transaction_no,settlement_account _no, amount,sbp_unique_identifier,transaction_date,identifier_no,depositor_name,ecpr,bank_name,is_process,process_date,iss_error,error_message,is_reconcile,remarks,isactive,entry_date)
    values 
       (v_sbp_file_conf_detail_id,v_sbp_file_conf_id,i.file_sr_no,i.payment_id,i.channel_transaction_no,i.settlement_account_no,i.amount,i.sbp_unique_identifier,i.transaction_date,i.identifier_no,i.depositor_name,i.ecpr,i.bank_name,null,null,null,null,null,null,1,sysdate);
                                       
  end loop;
                                  
  p_flag := v_sbp_file_conf_id;
  commit;
   
Exception 
    when others then
      APP_OPTIONS.LOG_BUG('SBP File Conf Det ID='||v_sbp_file_conf_detail_id||',
        p_error_codes: ERROR-'||sqlerrm, 
        'SYSTEM',                                                      
        'payment_gateway_mechanism_1.PG_ADC_API_SBP_FILE_BATCH');
      p_flag := -1;
    
end pg_adc_api_sbp_file_batch;

END PAYMENT_GATEWAY_MECHANISM_1;
```

Currently I have a class like below in which I am storing my data and want to send it to the UDT.

```
class FileBulkPost_Request
    {
        public string FileFullPath { get; set; }
        public int Total_Records { get; set; }
        public double Total_Amount { get; set; }
        public List<FileBulkPostRows> fileBulkPostRows { get; set; }
    }

    class FileBulkPostRows
    {
        public int File_Sr_No { get; set; }
        public long Payment_ID { get; set; }
        public string Channel_Transaction_No { get; set; }
        public double Amount { get; set; }
        public double PSID_Amount { get; set; }
        public string Settlement_Account_No { get; set; }
        public string Unique_Identifier { get; set; }
        public string Depositor_Name { get; set; }
        public string Taxpayer_NTN { get; set; }
        public string Identifier_No { get; set; }
        public string ECPR { get; set; }
        public string Bank_Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime Transaction_Date { get; set; }

    }
```

Below is the code for binding in CLASS

```
objFilePost_Request.Total_Records = excelDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count; //
objFilePost_Request.Total_Amount = Convert.ToDouble(Total_Amount); // 
      //objFilePost_Request.FileID = 0;
objFilePost_Request.FileFullPath = validdestFile;

if (objFilePost_Request.Total_Records > 0)
  {
    objFilePost_Request.fileBulkPostRows = new 
    List<FileBulkPostRows>();
    foreach (DataRow PreparedPaymentsDatatRow in  excelDataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
      {
        var rownew = new FileBulkPostRows();
        if (PreparedPaymentsDatatRow["Sr"] == null || 
            PreparedPaymentsDatatRow["Sr"].ToString() == "")
          continue;
        else
         {
           //objFilePost_Request.fileBulkPostRows.Add();
           rownew.File_Sr_No = Convert.ToInt32(PreparedPaymentsDatatRow["Sr"]);
         }
     rownew.Payment_ID= Convert.ToInt64(PreparedPaymentsDatatRow["PSID"]); 
     rownew.Channel_Transaction_No=PreparedPaymentsDatatRow["Tran ID"].ToString();
     rownew.Settlement_Account_No= PreparedPaymentsDatatRow["Govt Account Number"].ToString();
     rownew.Bank_Name= PreparedPaymentsDatatRow["Bank Name"].ToString();
     rownew.Amount= Convert.ToDouble(PreparedPaymentsDatatRow["Amount"]);
     rownew.Unique_Identifier= PreparedPaymentsDatatRow["Unique Identifier"].ToString();

     DateTime transactionDate = DateTime.MinValue;
     String Y = PreparedPaymentsDatatRow["Transaction Date"].ToString().Substring(0, 4);
     String M = PreparedPaymentsDatatRow["Transaction Date"].ToString().Substring(4, 2);
     String D = PreparedPaymentsDatatRow["Transaction Date"].ToString().Substring(6, 2);
      
     rownew.Transaction_Date = Convert.ToDateTime(M + '/' + D + '/' + Y);
     rownew.Depositor_Name = PreparedPaymentsDatatRow["Depositor Name"].ToString();
     rownew.Identifier_No = PreparedPaymentsDatatRow["Taxpayer NTN"].ToString();
     rownew.ECPR = PreparedPaymentsDatatRow["ECPR"].ToString();
     
     objFilePost_Request.fileBulkPostRows.Add(rownew);
  }
```

I need a way to send this object to oracle SP